# In GoogleSheet , IMPORTDATA stops working

Tags: csv, google-sheets, download, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to download csv file into google sheet. Link is as below:

https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv

If we click on above csv link , file starts downloading without any issue. 
I used below for importing
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv")
However it shows an error "could not fetch URL" 
I also tried **http** instead of **https** but that also did not work.

Any suggestion?